# How to associate dynamic value with HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sql, web

I want to create a list which is clickable and which would allow me to take a survey when I click it.

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Take Survey
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <div class="list-group">
      { for search in searches }
      <a href="\take" class="list-group-item">{{search.topic}}</a>
      { endfor }
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I click it I want it to go to a page which shows the questions of the survey whose topic was being shown.
I have created SQL tables for users,surveys,questions and options. Surveys are linked to users, questions are linked to surveys and options are linked to questions.

I just need a way to access the survey id({{search.id}}) in my take route where I could run a SQL query using the survey id to link everything.

Just a disclaimer, I am a beginner in HTML so please try to explain elaborately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways that you can do this with html, here are a few of them

- create a hidden input with the value that u need, and later when u need it retrieve it from that input

```
 <input type="hidden" id="searchId" name="searchId" value="3487">
```

- add a custom attribute to an element, and later when needed retrieve it from that element

```
<div class="list-group">
      { for search in searches }
      <a href="\take" class="list-group-item">{{search.topic}} data-search-id="{{search.id}}"</a>
      { endfor }
    </div>
```

There are also multiple ways you can do this without html

- insert a script that has the search id, and later retrieve that id from javascript

```
{% block main %}
    <div class="list-group">
      { for search in searches }
      <a href="\take" class="list-group-item">{{search.topic}}</a>
      { endfor }
       <script>
       // just make sure that this variable is unique, so u dont cause errors or overwrite another variable by mistake
       const MY_APP_SEARCH_ID ={{search.id}}
       </script>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

- You could also generate a unique url for each survey

```
 <a href="\take?searchId={{search.id}}" class="list-group-item">{{search.topic}} </a>
```

and then handle that search id from the \take endpoint

Comment: @APE if this answered your question, then marking it as an answer and liking it, will make it easier for others to find it

Comment: I marked it as an answer but I have less than 15 reputation so my upvote is not displayed.

Comment: Also could you tell me how to access it in a flask route.You seem to know your stuff.

Comment: @APE frankly i don't know about flask, but you can search for how to get url params from flask

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured out how to pass the data.